# Test if Excel is open without relying on catching an error

Tags: vba, error-handling, excel

Getting a hook on an open instance of Excel is something I do all the time. I'm now questioning if I'm doing this the best way. I'm particularly concerned with the fact that I rely on the `GetObject` method to throw an error. I'd like to avoid it if possible.

I have a Utils module that contains a function that returns a brand new instance of excel and one that tries to get an open instance of excel. When I encounter Err.Number 429 in the `GetExcelApp` function, I call the `CreateExcelApp` function. Something I've done routinely for years suddenly feels dirty. There has to be a better way to do this.

```
Public Function GetExcelApp() As Excel.Application
' Returns open excel instance.
'   If it doesn't exist, creates one to return
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Const ERR_APP_NOTRUNNING As Long = 429    

    Set GetExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

CleanExit:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    If Err.number = ERR_APP_NOTRUNNING Then
        Set GetExcelApp = CreateExcelApp
    Else
        ShowErrorMessageBox
    End If
End Function

Private Function CreateExcelApp() As Excel.Application
' Returns New instance of Excel
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set CreateExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

CleanExit:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ShowErrorMessageBox
End Function

Private Sub ShowErrorMessageBox()
    ErrHandler.messageBox "Utils", "GetExcelApp", vbCritical, "Unable to get an instance of Excel."
End Sub
```

This code does also rely on this subroutine in an external module named ErrHandler.

```
Public Sub messageBox(moduleName As String, procName As String, Optional style As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbCritical, Optional OptionalText As String = vbNullString)
    Dim messageText As String
    messageText = "Module: " & moduleName & vbCrLf & _
                "Procedure: " & procName & vbCrLf & _
                Err.Description

    If Not OptionalText = vbNullString Then
        messageText = messageText & vbCrLf & OptionalText
    End If

    MsgBox messageText, style, "Runtime Error: " & Err.number

End Sub
```

And here is a quick example of how the GetExcelApp function is used.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Set xl = GetExcelApp
    xl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I also read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164798%28v=office.10%29.aspx), but they're using `On Error Resume Next`... That's not even remotely acceptable.

Comment: Just to clarify, this isn't Excel-VBA, right?

Comment: General concept. Most often done from Access. Sometimes from Word. It's platform independent as far as VBA is concerned.

Comment: True, but running this code in Excel would be a little.. you know.. ;)

Comment: Umm yeah. Running it in Excel would always return itself. Wouldn't make much sense. =;)-

Comment: Is `ErrHandler` a *code module* (.bas) or a *class module* (.cls)?

Comment: *code* module. *.bas file.

Comment: You might be able to modify [what I used to catch IE popups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446951/how-to-intercept-and-manipulate-a-internet-explorer-popup-with-vba) to catch an existing instance of Excel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was pointed out in chat earlier, a module called `Utils` might as well be called `Helpers` or `DumpAnythingYouWantHere`.

You should prefer using `vbNewLine` over `vbCrLf`: `vbNewLine` will produce a platform-specific new line, while code that uses `vbCrLf` might only produce correct results under Windows, which means your comment about it being *platform-independent* is a false assumption.

I get the `GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` call to tap into the current instance (what happens when there are 2 or more instances already opened?), but the `CreateExcelApp` function could be much, much more straightforward than this:

> ```
> Private Function CreateExcelApp() As Excel.Application
> ' Returns New instance of Excel
> On Error GoTo ErrHandler
>
>     Set CreateExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
>
> CleanExit:
>     Exit Function
> ErrHandler:
>     ShowErrorMessageBox
> End Function
> ```

Consider:

```
Private Function CreateExcelApp() As Excel.Application
    Set CreateExcelApp = New Excel.Application
End Function
```

At which point I'd question the need for this `CreateExcelApp` function! Why not simply handle that in `GetExcelApp`? Like the comments say, *if it doesn't exist, creates one to return*:

```
Public Function GetExcelApp() As Excel.Application
' Returns open excel instance.
'   If it doesn't exist, creates one to return
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Const ERR_APP_NOTRUNNING As Long = 429    

    Set GetExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

CleanExit:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    If Err.number = ERR_APP_NOTRUNNING Then
        Set GetExcelApp = New Excel.Application
        Resume CleanExit
    Else
        ShowErrorMessageBox
    End If
End Function
```

I don't like `ShowErrorMessageBox`. It's `Private` and single-use, with a hard-coded message that's only relevant for an error occurring in `GetExcelApp`. I'd get rid of that method.

Comment: I didn't know that about vbCrLf. Thanks for the tip. I meant to say *applicataion* independent though. =) I was over engineering again... Thanks @Mat'sMug.

Comment: I looked into the situation where more than one instance is already open. It appears that it returns the last instance to be started, but I don't think there's any guarantee which instance it will return. Which is *ok* for my purposes, but not ideal.